# Run if/else executable from terminal single input

Tags: bash

I have an executable program that takes if/else user inputs and I want to run it from a bash terminal in one line, i.e. without having to go through the program prompts.

Is there a way to pass echo commands?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your program is reading data line by line, then you can do the following in bash.

```
{
    echo "input 1"
    echo "input 2"
    echo "input 3"
    ...
    echo "input n"
} | my-program
```

The `{}` creates a command group, and the outputs of the commands within that group are piped to `my-program`.

An alternate approach is to use a heredoc, which can be written as follows:

```
{
cat <<EOM
input 1
input 2
input 3
...
input n
EOM
} | my-program
```

Note that the `EOM` string to terminate the heredoc must be on a line by itself, therefore, you need to either create a command group or a subshell to ensure that the `cat` command doesn't send its output directly to your shell STDOUT, but instead to the pipe.